# Is it possible to see the URL salesforce generates through lightning connect

Tags: integration, lightning-connect, odata

We are trying to connect to a dell boomi service with oData 2.0 but boomi is having an issue consuming the URL and parsing parameters.

We do not have access to the boomi service, but is it possible to see the URL salesforce generates to retrieve the data from within salesforce?

We created an indirect lookup to accounts from this service and added the related list to the account layout. When we access an account the related list contains an error with a URL in it. However boomi is displaying a completely different URL.

URL from the related list

`http://...../ws/odata2/salesmine/Salesmine?$top=51&$filter=ID_SoldToSite+eq+'0000123123'&$inlinecount=allpages&$select=ID_SoldToSite`

URL from boomi
`GET /ws/odata2/salesmine/Salesmine?$top=6&$filter=substringof('sandra+de+bock',OrderCreateDate)+eq+true+or+substringof('sandra+de+bock',SalesDocNumber)+eq+true+or+substringof('sandra+de+bock',FirstName)+eq+true+or+substringof('sandra+de+bock',LastName)+eq+true+or+substringof('sandra+de+bock',CustomerPONumber)+eq+true+or+substringof('sandra+de+bock',OrderNetTotal)+eq+true+or+substringof('sandra+de+bock',ID_SoldToSite)+eq+true&$inlinecount=allpages&$select=ID_SoldToSite`

Is it possible to debug the URL salesforce is generating and log that into a log file from within salesforce?